# How to cancel the click trigger of the mouse input if the it moved after clicking?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying for almost 24 hours to resolve this

I have an object in my scene that, when clicked, will trigger to move to another scene. I would like the behavior of this object click to be exactly like a UI Button.

I'm currently using the Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) to trigger this event. The problem is I have a script attached to the main camera that makes it rotate, zoom, and pan around in the scene. If the user accidentally ends up releasing the mouse on that object after moving the camera around, this will trigger the event since the object is considered clicked.

I would like to prevent that from happening. I was thinking about cancelling the event in case a mouse movement was detected, I couldn't execute it. Or maybe there would be a better approach to solve the problem.

I would really appreciate the help

**My code below:**

```
private void LateUpdate()
{

    //When mouse button is released
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {


            RaycastHit hit;
            //Create a ray that projects at the position of the clicked mouse position
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            //If the ray hits the target object
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
            {
            //Load the scene that corresponds to the clicked object
            LoadScene(hit.transform.gameObject);
            }

    }
}


public void LoadScene(GameObject go)
{
    //Load the level that corresponds to the clicked object
    SceneManager.LoadScene(go.name);
    //Print the name of the clicked object
    print(go.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I just found a solution, I added a term that if the mouse moves to do nothing, my new code:

private void LateUpdate()
    {

```
    //When mouse button is released
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {

        //If the mouse moves after clicking
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < 0 || (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") > 0))
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
        else {
            //If no movement is detected, then send ray to object and trigger event
            RaycastHit hit;
            //Create a ray that projects at the position of the clicked mouse position
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            //If the ray hits the target object
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
            {
                //Load the scene that corresponds to the clicked object
                LoadScene(hit.transform.gameObject);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most click implementations detect both the mouse down and mouse up events to determine if an object was clicked.

I would suggest something like this...

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
    mouseWasPressedOverObject = IsMouseOverObject();
} else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
    if(mouseWasPressedOverObject && IsMouseOverObject()) {
        //Object clicked
    }
    mouseWasPressedOverObject = false;
}
```